# Azure Data Factory copy activity with json data

Tags: azure-data-factory, azure-synapse

I am using a copy activity with request method as POST to copy the JSON response from a rest api. The rest api requires a body which contains date and time details in the below format

[
{
"start_date": "2023-02-07"
"start_time": "06:42:06"
"end_date": "2023-02-07"
"end_time": "08:47:06"

}
]

When am using the date and time as hardcoded values like the one shown above, it works fine. When I try to make it dynamic i.e. startdate as currentdate - 1 and start time as current time - 24hrs and end date as currentdate and end time as current time its failing.
In simple words I want to make the body of the api as dynamic

I tried the end date as "{@formatdatetime(utcnow(),'yyyy-MM-dd')}"
and end time as end time as "{@formatdatetime(utcnow(),'hh-MM-ss')}"

and few other combinations of the above code but its failing. Can someone please help me with this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Used a set variable activity to create the dynamic date & time separately and then used the output of the variable in the body of copy activity.

Answer (score 0):

- Since I don't have access to a REST API like yours, I have taken `set variable` activities to demonstrate how to create the required body using dynamic content.
- I have used `addDays()` function to remove 1 day from both current date (1 day) and current time (24 hours and hence 1 day).
- Then I have formatted the result using formatDateTime in the following way:

```
[ { "start_date": "@{formatDateTime(addDays(utcNow(),-1),'yyyy-MM-dd')}" "start_time": "@{formatDateTime(addDays(utcNow(),-1),'hh:mm:ss')}" "end_date": "@{formatDateTime(utcNow(),'yyyy-MM-dd')}" "end_date": "@{formatDateTime(utcNow(),'hh:mm:ss')}"} ]
```

[image]

- The result would be as shown below:

[image]

Comment: Thank you @Saideep for the response on this. You may be right. But I used a set variable before the copy activity to have the dynamic date and time and then in the copy activity used the variable to pass it to the JSON.

Answer (score 0):

The JSON block which you shared is not a JSON itself , I am wondering as to how this is working when you hardcoded .

I see that you are using `@formatdatetime(utcnow(),'hh-MM-ss')` to me it looks like you should use `@formatdatetime(utcnow(),'hh-mm-ss'`

** MM is for month

** mm is for minute